# Definite integral of a non integrable function(in terms of elementary functions)

Tags: calculus

How can I evaluate something like this:

$$\int _a^{b}\:\frac{1}{\log\left(x\right)}\,dx$$

I've tried introducing a "y" variable to solve it using the differentiation 
technique, but it does not work. So, is there another method to solving this?

Thank you.

Comment: I would be shocked if it had a closed form solution.

Comment: for example sin(x)/x doesn't have an indefinite integral, but you can compute its definite integrals. I would like to know if this funtion shares that feature too. @Randall

Comment: What technique do you use to compute definite integrals of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Comment: introducing the y variable @Randall

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I have no idea what that is.

Comment: okay maybe what i just said isn't true for sin(x)/x, but it works for other functions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule @Randall

Comment: @DavidSousa There is no elementary closed form for this. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Comment: yeah i know (its written in the title), but sometimes definite integrals can be computed for integrals with no closed form. @Srini

Comment: I think @Srini 's point is that this integral has been studied by lots of people for a long time and the only thing we have is asymptotic (not exact) knowledge, so I wouldn't get my hopes up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I$ be the integral

$$I=\int_a^b\frac{1}{\log(x)}\,dx$$

where it is assumed that the point $x=1$ is not contained in $[a,b]$.

Enforcing the substitution $x= e^{-u}$ yields

$$I=\int_{-\log(a)}^{-\log(b)}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}\,du=-\int_{-\log(b)}^{-\log(a)}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}\,du\tag1$$

The Exponential Integral [See Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definitions), $\text{Ei}(x)$, is defined by

$$\text{Ei}(x)=-\int_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-u}}{u}\,du\tag2$$

Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ we see that

$$I=\text{Ei}(\log(b))-\text{Ei}(\log(a))$$

> Hence, the integral $I$ is not expressible in terms of elementary functions, but can be expressed in terms of the special function, the Exponential Integral.

Answer (score 1):

The logarithmic or exponential integrals are not an elementary function, but since the logarithm function grows very slowly, the given integral is fairly easy to approximate numerically, especially if the $(a,b)\subset(1,+\infty)$ interval is fairly short. For instance
$$ \int_{2}^{3}\frac{dx}{\log x}\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}\left[\frac{x}{\log x}\right]_{2}^{3}+\int_{2}^{3}\frac{dx}{\log^2 x} $$
and $\int_{2}^{3}\frac{dx}{\log^2 x}\approx \frac{1}{\log^2\frac{5}{2}}$. $\text{IBP}$ stands for Integration By Parts, of course.